# How do I check Memory leakage in solaris server?

Tags: solaris, memory-leaks

I need to check memory leakage on my Solaris server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the libumem interposition library and mdb findleaks function.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/memory_leak_detection_with_libumem and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656981/solaris-libumem-why-not-show-memory-leak-for-first-dynamic-allocation

Comment: void main()
{
    void *buff;
    buff = malloc(128);
    buff = malloc(60);
    buff = malloc(30);
    buff = malloc(16);
    free(buff);
    sleep(180);
} 
is this work on your system for memory leakage? kindly let me know.....

Comment: The three leaks produced by this code are properly detected on my system (Solaris 11.3).

Comment: ok. i am actually new in here... it would be very grateful if you tell me what is the overall procedure to check my servers memory leakage?

Comment: The overall procedure is to monitor your system to identify which processes, if any, show a raising memory consumption, then to relaunch them with using libumem. When the memory usage is sufficient, generate and analyze their core images with mdb. Note that java processes should be monitored and analyzed with different tools.

Comment: how do I check memory leakage by using dtrace?

Comment: There is no simple, generic way to use dtrace to find memory leaks but it can be very helpful to explore further when you have an idea of how the leak is generated. Your question is too broad.